# Ubuntu 14.04 right click on folder (for properties) not working

Tags: icons, clock, ifolder

I not able to right click on each folder or file on my system Also files and folder attach with clock icon.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens if you select on item (by single left-click) and then hit `shift+F10` on your keyboard? If I remember correctly `shift-F10` is the right-click shortcut on Nautilus...

Comment: When we right click property option not working